# Is there some way to manually send newly registered users in Joomla to Mautic?

Tags: joomla, mautic

Mautic's Joomla integration plugin says it can send newly registered users as leads back to Mautic. Unfortunately for me, it does not work no matter what I do. I do believe that I did correctly what is instructed on the plugins' GitHub page so I don't know now what to do.

I'm currently running on a hosting service that uses cPanel, having PHP 5.4.45, and running Apache version 2.4.38. Installation of Mautic seems fine as there are no errors found when I installed it.

Comment: can you please screenshot your settings within Joomla plugin (blur password) and the link to your mautic installation

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @YellowWebMonkey
Here's the link of the screenshot. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ropPFY5NQmyRLZfB06J4G7Sl1Rovz09-/view) 
The mautic is in a subdirectiory on our web folder.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so that, Manual send will be a good idea but you can do this with mautic API.

But you are using PHP 5.4 that means you are using a outdated mautic instance.
So first of all just update the mautic version and also update the PHP version to 7.2.
To update mautic version please follow this [link steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58335523/6592882)

Then follow this link https://mautic.com/help/use-mautic-joomla/ to reconfigure the API.

If still your issue is not resolve then follow this [Mautic Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EZ7nTW5CdE)

I thing this will be helpful for you.