# The site is currently offline due to encountering an error - Mautic

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, mautic

After upgrade my server version (Plesk Onyx with debian) I have recreated the domain and database with all the same DB, Users and Password, but mautic show this:

The site is currently offline due to encountering an error. If the problem persists, please contact the system administrator. System administrators, check server logs for errors.

All the necessary php modules are Active and work about pdo, pdo_mysql etc etc.

[image: Php Setting Screenshot]

### Additional Information

Mautic version |  Last
PHP version | 7.2.19
Browser | Tested with all Browser
Server | Plesk Onyx Version 17.8.11 - Debian 9.9

### Steps to reproduce

I have change the server. My previous server version was in CENTOS, now is DEBIAN whit the last version of Plesk Onyx.

I have made Backup of FTP and MySQL, and i have recreate the main domain and the sub domain where MAUTIC are on the root directory sub.mysite.ext.

I have reused same DB Name, DB user and Password, and the DB address is always localhost on port 3306.

I have try to cancel the Cache, but nothing.
I have try to set the right permission by console:
cd /var/www/vhost/thisismywebsite.ext/mautic.thisismywebsite.ext/
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod -R g+w app/cache/
chmod -R g+w app/logs/
chmod -R g+w app/config/
chmod -R g+w media/files/
chmod -R g+w media/images/
chmod -R g+w translations/

but again don't work

On my new server i have a new version of MySQL, 10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.8
On my previous version MySql version was 5.5.60-MariaDB

#### Log errors

`[2019-06-21 11:02:29] mautic.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException: "An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE users SET online_status = ? WHERE last_active <= ?' with params ["offline", "2019-06-21 08:47:29"]:  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_mmautic.users' doesn't exist" at /var/www/vhosts/thisismysite.ext/mautic.thisismysite.ext/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 53 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\TableNotFoundException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE users SET online_status = ? WHERE last_active <= ?' with params [\"offline\", \"2019-06-21 08:47:29\"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_mmautic.users' doesn't exist at /var/www/vhosts/thisismysite.ext/mautic.thisismysite.ext/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:53, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_mmautic.users' doesn't exist at /var/www/vhosts/thisismysite.ext/mautic.thisismysite.ext/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:107, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_mmautic.users' doesn't exist at /var/www/vhosts/thisismysite.ext/mautic.thisismysite.ext/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:105)"} []
[2019-06-21 11:02:29] mautic.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException: An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE users SET online_status = ? WHERE last_active <= ?' with params ["offline", "2019-06-21 08:47:29"]:  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_mmautic.users' doesn't exist at /var/www/vhosts/thisismysite.ext/mautic.thisismysite.ext/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 53) {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\TableNotFoundException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE users SET online_status = ? WHERE last_active <= ?' with params [\"offline\", \"2019-06-21 08:47:29\"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_mmautic.users' doesn't exist at /var/www/vhosts/thisismysite.ext/mautic.thisismysite.ext/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:53, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_mmautic.users' doesn't exist at /var/www/vhosts/thisismysite.ext/mautic.thisismysite.ext/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:107, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin_mmautic.users' doesn't exist at /var/www/vhosts/thisismysite.ext/mautic.thisismysite.ext/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:105)"} []
[2019-06-21 11:02:29] mautic.ERROR: Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException: An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE users SET online_status = ? WHERE last_active  [] []`

### Heeelp

Please i'm going crazy. Some one can help me?

Comment: Seems like you need to run the installer <if any> to create all tables again. Error clearly shows `admin_mmautic.users` table dosen't exists.

Comment: so i need to Over Install a new version? really i don't know how to

Comment: yes, seems like tables are removed and only using installer you can restore all tables required.

Comment: it's impossible run installation script without loosing all data from database...!

Answer (score 1):

Some times this is due to server permission issue, Mautic need write permission for the instance's server file so,

- Give the write permission
- Clear the cache `php app/console cache:clear`
- Give again permission
- Refresh the dashboard page

It will work fine.

**OR**

If the issue is not solved with the above process then you have to update the Mautic version to over come this issue.

To **Update Mautic** instance, please follow the below steps

> 1. First get the backup of the code (`zip -r filename.zip  project folder path`).
> 2. Get the database backup (`mysqldump  -h host -u username -p(password)  database name > projectname.sql`)
> 3. Give the file permission and clear the cache. By using (`php app/console cache:clear` or `rm -rf app/cache`).
> 4. Check if there is any update available. By using (`php app/console mautic:update:find`).
> 5. If there is any update available then update the instance.
>    By using (`php app/console mautic:update:apply`).
> 6. Now give the file permission and remove the cache again.
> 7. Now done the instance is updated and test it. That’s it.

If still you issue is not solve then you can update the **mysql database schema**.
To do this please follow the link https://www.mautic.org/docs/en/tips/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Did you give this a try?

Comment: It was a server permission error for me. Making sure the files were owned by the right user worked. In my case: `chown -R nginx:nginx .`

Answer (score 0):

I would just double check that your new system is using the same prefix for your database tables, and that they have all been moved over using the same database name.

Specifically, look in your Mautic configuration (app/config/local.php) and check the database connection details (db_host, db_name, db_port, db_user, db_password) prefix (db_table_prefix), etc and ensure they match what you're seeing in your database.

In your error logs above, it seems that you are trying to find the table:

admin_mmautic.users

The errors are telling you that this table doesn't exist.

Maybe a typo (admin_mmautic seems like an unusual prefix to me) or that before the prefix was different on your old server and did not include admin at the start?